Designing a simple toy dashboard
I would like to make a "car dashboard" simulator as a gift for my kid. Nothing too complicated. Here are my initial thoughts, and I would like to hear your opinions - where I was wrong, what should be changed (and why). Have in mind that my electronics knowledge was zero just a week ago.

1 power source (a 9V battery)
1 "main" switch, to turn on/off the whole circuit
1 capacitor (not sure which capacity is enough), wired in parallel with the battery and the main switch, to somewhat protect the circuit from voltage jumps and drops if the kid starts playing too much with the main switch
Left "turn indicator": 3 red blinking LEDs wired in parallel + 1 green blinking LED (also in parallel with the red ones). Each LED will have a resistor (I still have to calculate the resistance value) wired in series with it, to limit the current to ~20mA. There will also be a switch to turn the whole group on and off. I found blinking LEDs in an electronics store, so I don't need any additional timer/controller/anything like that.
Right "turn indicator": Same as the left one
"Headlights": 2 groups of 3 white LEDs each + 1 blue LED, and they will all be wired in parallel. Again, each LED will have a corresponding resistor, and there will be a switch for the whole group.
I would also like to have one LED (yellow, let's say), which will turn on when the main switch is turned on.

Here are my questions:

Do I need the capacitor? I think I know the pros and cons, but I'd like to hear your opinions. Which capacity should I choose and why?
Do I maybe need some additional capacitors for the "sub-circuits", to protect them from the hectic switching on and off?
How to deal with groups of LEDs which have different forward voltages and to make them have the same light intensity (e.g. in the "turn indicator" groups the red LEDs have a voltage drop of 2V, and the green ones will have 3V)? I guess I should play with different resistor values, but I'm not 100% sure...
I guess that putting LEDs in parallel is better practice than putting them in series? In the first case, I would have much higher current, and in the second case I would need much higher voltage. I did some calculations and the max current in my circuit would be ~200mA. Is this dangerous?
How to wire the yellow LED which will stay on as long as the main switch is on? If it's in series with the main switch and it fails, the whole circuit will lose power. If it's somehow wired in parallel, it will short the whole circuit and burn out. I guess I could add a big resistor, but then the rest of the circuit will have much less current available... Not sure what to do here.

Here's an initial schema made in Tinkercad (no yellow LED in there):

Tinkedcad link (I've just changed the visibility from private to public and it's still "pending", so you might not be able to open it yet): https://www.tinkercad.com/things/6cmdrf8hB4q-toy-car-dashboard
One more question: can anyone recommend a free, easy-to-use online tool for drawing schematics and possibly calculating the currents and voltages? I couldn't find any in the last week...
UPDATE:
I bought the required components and I ran into the first issue that I don't really understand. I parallelly connected three red blinking LEDs and one green blinking LED to test them. Each one of them has a 330 Ohm resistor in series. There is a 9V battery powering up everything. For some reason, the LEDs are not blinking at the same time. At first I thought - ok, the green LED and the red LED have different blinking frequencies for some reason... But then I saw that the three red LEDs were blinking out of sync as well. It's like every single LED has a different frequency. What could be the reason?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Although calculating the currents for LEDs is easy enough, the missing factor is how bright they are for a given current, which is extremely difficult to tell from a datasheet.  (I mean how bright it actually looks.)  So especially for a one off type of device, consider just testing with various LEDs and resistors until it looks right.  And for diagrams of this simplicity, consider squared paper and a pencil.

Your post has several questions in it; here are some answers:
You do not need a capacitor for this.
Individual resistors for the LEDs are required, but some blinking LEDs may not require resistors at all. Put them in parallel and adjust current with individual resistors.
LEDs can be modulated at MHz frequencies, a human working a switch will not damage them by turning them on and off too rapidly.
The yellow LED can be placed across the output of the main switch and the turn switches can be in parallel.
High intensity white and blue LEDs can damage your eyes if you look directly at them.
Use alkaline batteries, probably 4 AAs; their internal resistance makes them incapable of some failure modes a Li-ion battery could experience.
Our built in schematic tool will work well for your needs.

For a childrens toy, especially DIY, I will suggest never to use rechargeable batteries. They can pump up 20x more current than standard alkaline cells, and thus rechargeables are capable of turning wires red hot, melt the insulation, and the glowing wires can start fires. This is the main reason toys suggest to use primary batteries, not the voltage difference of rechargeables, even if people complain they have to buy new batteries constantly. Toys are hopefully these days mandated by safety standards, not convenience for using unsafe rechargeables with them.

Good point, I'll strike that out.

In addition to what vir said in their answer, and specifically regarding your self-flashing LEDs:

There will be a 'tolerance' on how accurately the flash duration is, this can be seen on YouTube when searching for "BigClive Supercomputer". If you put the LEDs in parallel, they will lose synchronisation from one another, although how quickly this will happen I cannot say - for a one-off it may be possible to hand-pick 'matched' LEDs in terms of flash duration, but more generally speaking this is best avoided. This tolerance can be large as discussed at the end of this answer.

